# Laravel Create Eloquent Instance from ManyToOne Relationship Error SQLSTATE[23000]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to create instance using Laravel 5 Eloquent Relationship.

I have 2 Migrations and 2 Eloquent Model.

Companies Migration:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCompaniesTable extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('Companies', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->string('CompanyCode', 15);
            $table->string('Name', 200);
            $table->string('Type', 100);
            $table->tinyInteger('IsActive')->default(1);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->primary('CompanyCode');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('Companies');
    }

}
```

Company Model:

```
namespace App\Models\Setting\Organization;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Model {

    protected $fillable = ['CompanyCode', 'Name', 'Type'];

    public function organizationUnits(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Setting\Organization\OrganizationUnit', 'CompanyCode');
    }
}
```

OrganizationUnits Migration:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateOrganizationUnitsTable extends Migration {

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('OrganizationUnits', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->string('OrganizationUnitCode', 15); //PK
            $table->string('CompanyCode', 15); //FK
            $table->string('Name', 200);
            $table->tinyInteger('IsActive')->default(1);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->primary('OrganizationUnitCode');
            $table->foreign('CompanyCode', 'OrgUnits_Company_FK')
                  ->references('CompanyCode')
                  ->on('Companies')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
        });

    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('OrganizationUnits');
    }

}
```

OrganizationUnit Model:

```
namespace App\Models\Setting\Organization;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class OrganizationUnit extends Model {

    protected $table = "OrganizationUnits";

    protected $fillable = ['OrganizationUnitCode', 'CompanyCode', 'Name'];

    public function company(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Setting\Organization\Company', 'CompanyCode');
    }

}
```

The relationship is one Company may have one or more OrganizationUnit, one OrganizationUnit must have one and only one Company.

I tried to create new instance of OrganizationUnit in `php artisan tinker` using this code:

```
$company = \App\Models\Setting\Organization\Company::first();
$orgunit = $company->organizationUnits()->create(['OrganizationUnitCode' => 'abcdef']);
```

But Laravel gives the following error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'CompanyCode' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `OrganizationUnits` (`Org
>   anizationUnitCode`, `CompanyCode`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (abcdef, , 2015-12-17 00:17:33, 2015-12-17 00:17:33))'

Where did I go wrong? Please help. I'm new to Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

It clearly says that CompanyCode cannot be null. You can define it by hand or you can use the `increments` method on the Blueprint instance while creating your migration.

Comment: Hello @OzanKurt , thanks for the answer. I already tried using default value " " to the Foreign Key field in OrganizationUnits table, but laravel gives foreign key constraint error since there's no " " CompanyCode in Companies table.  

`$table->string('CompanyCode', 15)->default(" "); //FK`